# How to use Matplotlib plot markers in LaTex text

Tags: symbols, matplotlib

I want to use plot markers from [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html)
in Latex.
Especially I am looking for Latex equivalents of the symbols '1', '2', '3' and '4', as used for the 'two pairs' label in the plot.
I already looked into this [collection](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf) and this [online tool](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but did not find a similar symbol.

I thought that all the Matplotlib marker symbols have an equivalent in Latex.
[image: example plot]

Comment: I also found it in the `stmaryrd` package: `\Yup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (ab)use Ti*k*Z:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\wye[1][]{%
    \tikz\draw[thick, line cap=round,x=1ex,y=1ex,#1]
    (0,0) -- ++(90:1)
    (0,0) -- ++(-30:1)
    (0,0) -- ++(-150:1);
}
\begin{document}
The symbol for ``two pairs'' is \wye,
which can rotate as \wye[rotate=90] and/or
change color as in \wye[color=red].
\end{document}
```

[image]